# Functions and natural ordering

Tags: functions

Imagine that we have the following function:
$$
Y=f(X)
$$
where you can imagine $Y$ to be anything- say quantity of food consumed,
and $X$ is income. Now, when we think about counting objects, an
important property is that of order irrelevance, i.e. it does not
matter in which order you count, the amount you reach to is the same.
In the case of functions, you can imagine, say, my saying that if
$X=5,$ I consumed 10 units of food. Here, I don't see a natural ordering
of food or income. The 10 dollars I have could be counted in any which
way, as long as they add up to 10. On the other hand, when looking
at the derivative, $\frac{dY}{dX}$, a natural ordering is in fact
formed. This is because now, fixing $X$, as we increase $X$ by $\epsilon$,
$Y$ changes. I can now think of $X$ being,say the \emph{first five
}units of food, and now consuming the next little bit. My question
is this: is there an implied natural ordering in functions? In other
words, is there a 1:1 mapping between $X$ and the order of the objects?

My answer: You can imagine, say, my saying that real numbers have a natural order. Here, I don't see any functions. On the other hand, when you look at a function, the order lets you do calculus. Now when we think about using real numbers to represent anything- say quantity of food consumed, then you have implicitly fixed an ordering.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions do not require an ordering on the argument.  I can define a function from houses to the country they are in.  This does not impose any order at all.  When the domain of a function has a natural order, like the reals, the function values get a natural order based on the order of the variable values.  The reals have much more than a natural order, they are a metric space, so it makes sense to talk of the distance between two reals.  You need that if you are to take a derivative.

Comment: Following up with this, imagine that someone tells you that the population is X. To obtain that X, a counting method is employed. Is it fair to say that an order is fixed in this case? (the order of counting that is).

Comment: I wouldn't think so.  When we count the people we usually ignore the order we counted them in.  Certainly you can keep track of it and have a list of all the people in order.  I would call that a roster instead of a population count.  Now you have an order of the list.

Comment: OK. Now imagine that population is a value on the real number line (it would have to be as it is a number!). Along that line, the population attained is X. But, in this case, X represents the last object that has been counted, right? Alternatively, X-1 along this line represents the X-1st object that has been counted no?

Comment: That is exactly the sense of the roster I mentioned.  When one talks of a population, it usually does not single out members of the population-they are all viewed as interchangeable.  When you make a list, they are in order and you can talk of the first, second,... next to last, last.  It depends on what use you are making of it whether this is useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very helpful.

Comment: So sorry to bother you with this again- I am still not sure it is perfectly clear to me. It seems that there is an inherent order here. Imagine we say the population is a number 3. This is 1+1+1. Simply put, here, is there not a first one, a second one and the third one implicit here?

Comment: Only in the order you counted them.  When  you say the population is $3$ it doesn't talk of an order.  If they are all grouped together, I can count them at a glance without noting one as first.  For larger numbers you can group things by tens and count the tens.  Knowing the population does not give an order, listing it does.

Comment: Gotcha. In your comment, however, you say that the reals have a natural order, and if we use the reals to define population, say, then why does the population not have an order then?

Comment: How are you using  the reals to define the population?  You can certainly consider the population as a real instead of an integer, but you only get an order if you assign a real to each member of the population.  This is no different from listing them or counting them in order.

Comment: Ah I get it finally. I have no idea why I have been obsessing over this for so long. I think I understand the source of my confusion now. If we say that the population has simply a value X, there is no implicit ordering there. You make the statement that the only time there would be an ordering is we assigned a real to each member of the population. I contend, however, that to obtain a value X of the population in practice, there would have had to have been an ordering of some sort involved. I guess it is unimportant though.

Comment: Final follow up: I have been a bit OCD about this:  when you think of the number 3, which can be defined as (1+1+1)- there seems to be an order here, right? There is a 1 which comes first when we write the expression. Is the order not implicit then?